# Simple code spawning a process in C crashes. Why?

Tags: c, windows, spawn

The following program crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

int main() {
    puts("Hello!");
    return spawnlp(0, "notepad.exe", "notepad.exe", "test.txt");
}
```

Comment: Same as [your question of yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187986/how-do-i-know-when-i-ought-to-free-strings-in-c-returned-by-library-functions): the man has all you need: _The last member of argv must be a NULL pointer._

Comment: @LPs: It does have it. I have read it but I haven’t correctly processed it: when I read it, I assumed that this requirement applied to `spawnvp()` (which takes an array) and not to `spawnlp()` (which takes an argument list). Does it make me a fool or is `man` an ineffective aid? I guess I know your opinion already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the terminating NULL to be passed as part of argument list.

Without that terminator, the end of the argument list will not be known, system will continue reading which  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to access of invalid memory locations.